# what is "\" in a href tag and when is it used?

Tags: php

in the code below,

```
<a href=\"index.php?id={$row['id']}\">{$row['title']}</a>
```

Why are there two '\'s with the href tag? When I remove them and add "./" in front of the 'index.php', it doesn't work. Do they have somthing with the array( {$row['id]} ) that is being used in the id parameter? How do you think can I use this href tag without '\'s? When do we use '\' in a href tag?

Comment: It's a way of escaping the next character in the string.... otherwise the following `"` would be treated as the end of the string.... see the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Comment: extending @MarkBaker comment, if you echoing data inside double quotation mark, you need that character to escape. If you echo with single quote, then escaping is not needed. example: `echo '<a href="bla/bla">Bla bla</a>';`

Comment: 1. You haven't given the full snippet here - in this example, it creates invalid html, 2. It's just an `a` tag, `href` is an attribute

Comment: @MarkBaker Mark If you post, I will upvote you since you beat me to it ;)

Comment: whtat does 'escape' mean?

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the code snippet you copied from looks something like this:

```
<?php
echo "<a href=\"index.php?id={$row['id']}\">{$row['title']}</a>";
?>
```

the `\"` is used to indicate that the quote is a character and not the end of the string.
This is called "escaping"

Answer (score 0):

See characters like " and ' are used in HTML/JavaScript as well as php. So when u have to echo a string in PHP you echo like this: `echo "Hello"`

Now, what if that string itself had a ", like your case above.

So, we use \ character to escape the ", which is part of the string as in your example.

`echo "<a href=\"index.php?id={$row['id']}\">foo</a>";`

Answer (score 0):

The \ character in PHP escapes characters and tell's PHP to ignore whatever character is immediately ahead of it. They can be useful when you are trying to nest a string with the same type of quotes, such as the following:

`$sql = 'SELECT * FROM members WHERE memberid = \'0001\'';`

This is it's simplest usage, albeit has many other uses, as described here -> [PHP: Escape Sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)